# drupal commerce conditional checkout panes

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

I have used the following module to add a custom checkout pane to get some additional information from the user regarding the order.

https://drupal.org/project/commerce_fieldgroup_panes

I now need to apply a condition that if the order contain a product of specific product type then display this pane else hide it.

Can some one please guide me how can I do this.

I have found the following code from https://drupal.org/node/1807092 but I don't know how to modify it according my need. Looking for some help on how to modify & use this code.

```
<?php function commerce_conditional_panes_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter(&$checkout_panes, $form, &$form_state) {
global $user;
foreach($checkout_panes as $pane_name => &$pane_data) {
    // load current order
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
    // retrieve the value of controlling field
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    $control = $order->field_make['und']['0']['value'];
    // Perform switch to see what to do with each aircraft make
    switch ($control)
    {
       case "value1":
         break;
       case "value2":
         break;
       case "value3":
         break;
       case "value4":
         break;
       case "value5":
         break;
       case "value6":
         // ...we only need to override one of them
         if($pane_name == 'commerce_fieldgroup_pane__conditional_pane' && $pane_data['enabled']) {
           // the pane is enabled by default, so we need to disable it
           $pane_data['enabled'] = 0;
         }
         break;
       case "value6":
         break;
       case "value7":
         break;
       case "value8":
         break;
       default:
         break;
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

It's surely too late for your project... Anyway, you may use [Commerce Rules Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_rules_extra),  it adds the exact features you need :

> - Rules conditions : Total product of type quantity comparison : Total
>     of products of specified type and with a specified quantity
> - Rules actions : Change pane properties : Change visibility, page,
>     weight of a pane

Once you installed it, in checkout settings , set your pane as disabled by default and create a new rule

- event: Process checkout pane
- conditions: Total product of type quantity comparison

  - Parameter: Order: [commerce_order]
  - Product Type: YOUR PRODUCT TYPE
  - Operator: >, Quantity: 0
- action : Change pane properties

  - Parameter: Id of pane to change: YOUR PANE
  - Enabled: true
  - move to : checkout

Answer (score 0):

Kojo's answer will no longer work as the 'Commerce Rules Extra' no longer can be used to hide panes.

See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2083981#comment-9740753

"Looks like hook_commerce_order_view_alter doesn't exist anymore, you are right" - Perignon (module maintainer)

Comment: You should write here the most important link text, because your answer can be flaged as low quality.